# structure of metrics on a compact manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

is there a reference on the structure of the space of metrics on a compact manifold that induce a given measure $\mu $?

i have a given manifold $M$, a given measure $\mu$ with an everywhere positive $C^{\infty}$ density with respect to Lebesgue. i want to construct a metric in this class satisfying some additional properties.

more precisely, for a given metric $g$ inducing $\mu $, i want to keep a finite number $n$ of eigenfunctions $\{ f_i \}$ of the laplacian,
$$
\Delta _{g} f_i = \lambda _i f_i
$$
Then, i generate another family of $n$ functions $\{ f'_i \}$ as linear combinations of the $\{ f_i \}$. What i want to do is to construct a metric $g'$ inducing the same measure such that
$$
\Delta _{g'} f'_i = \lambda ' _i f'_i
$$

I am looking for coordinate-free (if possible) calculations including this kind of objects.

thanks,
nikos

Comment: variation of the laplacian? do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Two follow up questions: (1) is it true that, as your notations indicated, that you want those $n$ eigenvalues to be the same? (2) Can I assume that $f'_i$ should be obtained by $A_{ij} f_j$ where $A_{ij}$ is some (given, fixed) invertible matrix?

Comment: 1. corrected the misprint, 2. the matrix A is indeed invertible and constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

- Martin Bauer, Philipp Harms, Peter W. Michor: Sobolev metrics on the manifold of all Riemannian metrics. Journal of Differential Geometry 94, 2 (2013), 187-208. [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/rie-met2.pdf).